# about RegexKitLite linebreak

Tags: objective-c, line-breaks, regexkitlite

I'm use RegexKitLite to match some texts:

xxx**[abc]**xxx

and I want to match [abc],and use this regular:

`NSString *result = [@"xxx[abc]xxx" stringByMatching:@"\\[(.*)?\\]" capture:1];`

then, the result is [abc].But, if have linebreak in there:

xxx[ab
c]xxx

It's dosen't work.
I use ([\s\S]*), also dosen't math [abc].
How can I match this text?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `.` does not match new lines by default. You could use

```
 ... stringByMatching:@"(?s:\\[(.*)?\\])" ...
//                      ^^^^           ^
```

or supply the [RKLDotAll](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/#RKLRegexOptions_RKLDotAll) option with the [-stringByMatching:options:inRange:capture:error:](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/#NSString_RegexKitLiteAdditions__-stringByMatching%3aoptions%3ainRange%3acapture%3aerror%3a) method.

Alternatively, you could use the greedy variant

```
@"\\[([^\\]]*)\\]"   // \[  (  [ ^\] ]  )   \]
```